# What does "Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question" mean?

Tags: discussion

Could somebody please explain what "Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question" means?

I understand what the individual words mean, but not how they would apply to a question asked on this forum about how the contents of a TV show reflect events in the real world at the time of writing.

Surely any answer that included an example from an episode or a quote form a writer would count?

The existence of a storyline is a fact that can be cited, as is a comment made by a writer.

I'm getting a little fed up with people closing questions without providing usable information.

I would suggest that comments should not be allowed to be closed under these circumstances without an example of good practice being cited to guide the person asking the question on how to improve it.

Answer (score 5):

> Could somebody please explain what "Update the question so it can be answered with facts and citations. This will help others answer the question" means?

This is a standard piece of text which appears on any question closed under the **opinion-based** close reason. Another standard piece of text used to explain this close reason is:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.

The [/help/dont-ask](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page in the help centre provides some more information about what types of questions count as too opinion-based to work well in the SE system, largely based on the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) SE blog post from eleven years ago which laid out which types of subjective questions can work well on SE and which can't.

Comment: Under the context of your provided links, I think that the "close as opinion" does not make sense. The question did not ask opinions. It may have started with a bit of "this is the case", but it then asked for proof thereof. It does not invite short answers, but rather the chief complaint was that it required a bit too much of a long form.

Comment: Ultimately, I think that your comments on the Literature SE ring true, that this might just not be a good match for the SF&F SE because we tend to shy away from analysis, mixed a bit with that I think the early iterations of the question seemed a lot more like they were seeking opinions or confirmation, which was all muddled by repeated reposting of the question with slight variations rather than just improving the question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you saw my edit on your original question before you deleted it, but after I made the edit, the question garnered 3 re-open votes and likely would have been re-opened and quite probably answered if it had stayed un-deleted*.

> I'm getting a little fed up with people closing questions without
> providing usable information.

This statement is demonstrably false. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that perhaps you didn't understand the commenters intent. However, several users made comments as to how to edit the question to make it more appropriate to the intent of the site, but those comments went unheeded and instead, (not trying to be rude here...) you argued with those users via comments.

I went ahead and made the edit to the original question after the second (duplicate) was asked and closed.

To re-state my comment in the edit, I think the germ of the question was a good one, but the question needed some editing to narrow the focus and remove any doubt of it being open to opinion.

**I myself may have taken a crack at answering, but to answer it well, it would take, me at least, a few hours to compile everything across the various series' and companion behind the scenes materials*.

Comment: There are too many gate keepers on this site and too few people willing to offer any form of usable guidance. It's probably going to be easier if I just post an extremely simple question asking about a different world event every week until I have enough information to go on.

Comment: gatekeepers, in a strict sense of the word, are exactly what the site intends and expects. Do you dispute the answer above @AaarghZombies? I apologize if you are feeling frustrated by the community's attempts to keep questions and answers limited to the scope of the site, but again, I think you had a good question at the core of what you posted and my edit was, I think, helpful. Alas if you feel different :)